# PHP persistent cookies in IE are disappearing when session ends

Tags: php, internet-explorer, cookies

I can't believe this is stumping me but...

The entire code for http://dev.mysite.com/cookie.php reads:

```
<?php
setcookie("foo", "bar", time()+2629743, "/", ".mysite.com");
var_dump($_COOKIE);
?>
```

The entire code for http://dev.mysite.com/cookie2.php reads:

```
<?php
var_dump($_COOKIE);
?>
```

I open IE9. I go to the first URL. Output is:

> array(0) { }

Not sure what's up with that, viewing the response headers in IE dev tools clearly shows the following:

```
Set-Cookie: foo=bar; expires=Thu, 08-Dec-2011 05:13:17 GMT; path=/; domain=.mysite.com
```

I refresh the page. Output is:

> array(1) { ["foo"]=> string(3) "bar" }

Ok, so there's my cookie. Again, viewing cookie info in dev tools shows me:

> NAME  foo
>   VALUE  bar
>   DOMAIN  mysite.com
>   PATH  /
>   EXPIRES 08/12/2011 05:24:00

Magic. Now I close IE down, reopen and go to the second URL. Which should just dump out all cookie contents. Output is:

> array(0) { }

Obviously I'm being quite astonishingly stupid somewhere, but where?

Comment: What’s the reference to sessions? And what session do you mean?

Comment: I mean a browser session. One that finishes when you close the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first part of your problem:

The `$_COOKIE` is not set in PHP *during* the first execution of PHP, it is simply communicated out to the browser. That's why it shows up the second time, because your browser is sending it back to PHP, and PHP is loading it in `$_COOKIE`.

Can you edit your post to show either actual examples of the domain text in the cookie or at least make the fictional domains consistent?

EDIT: Looking at the domain from your actual cookie listing in dev tools, I followed the exact steps you've outlined in your post. After shutting down IE8, I went back to the first page and the cookie info was there.

Your problem is in IE9 somewhere. Is there javascript setting/clobbering the same cookie? Does this loss happen with cookies for other sites in your IE9 installation?

Comment: This applies to all of the superglobals - they're populated as part of script startup, and then not touched by PHP again.

Comment: Oops. Edited the post. Thanks for the heads-up.

This is only happening with cookies on my site. Other cookies are persistent, for domains hosted on the same server.

It's also working on a colleague's IE8 though. Could this just be my IE9?

Comment: @Wintermute, it was actually helpful that you left that in, as I was able to exactly duplicate your steps and verify that it works in IE8. So you don't have a PHP problem. You have an IE9 problem.